# ExpressCheckout with recurring payments -- Cannot find solution

Tags: payment, checkout, recurring, paypal

I have been trying to set up an ExpressCheckout with recurring payments but I don't find the solution.

Having a look at the documentation ([Recurring Payments With the Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/)), the diagram gives a sequence where "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile" is invoked at the end.

Now, having a look at the other documentation ([How to Create a Recurring Payments Profile with Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/)), the different steps which are explained give a different sequence order, where "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile" comes directly after "GetExpressCheckoutDetails".

I tried to follow this second example but I systematically receive an error.

Could someone tell me what I exactly need to do?
Of course a practical example would be more than welcome...

In advance, many thanks

### Additional information:

The error I am receiving is "INVALID TOKEN".

Here is the information I send:

VERSION=84.0
METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
LOCALECODE=FR
TOKEN=[the one I received from SetExpressCheckout]
PROFILESTARTDATE=[the date of the next payment]
BILLINGPERIOD=Month
BILLINGFREQUENCY=6
TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=0
AMT=[the same as I mentioned in PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT]
AUTOBILLAMT=AddToNextBilling
CURRENCYCODE=EUR
MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=3
DESC=[the same as I mentioned in L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0]
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=[the same as I used in SetExpressCheckout]
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=[the same as I used in SetExpressCheckout]
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=[the same as I used in SetExpressCheckout]
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=[the same as I used in SetExpressCheckout]
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0=[the same as I used in SetExpressCheckout]

Do I also need to mention:
L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0 & L_BILLINGTYPE0 ?

Comment: @Machavity can i use Express checkout payment for monthly payment with  dynamic amount like(i have packages of channel and each package have some amount that is different.)and user pay for one month then this pack will renew next month automatically and amount is deduct . can i do this .

Comment: The error I am getting is "Invalid Token".

Answer (score 1):

In case you get **11502 Invalid token**, you will need to pass the following variables in your SetEC API request:

**BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION=Your billing agreement name**
**BILLINGTYPE=RecurringPayments**

Please, check below how EC+RP flow works:

1) SetExpressChekout + BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION and BILLINGTYPE variables

> VERSION = 86.0
>   METHOD = SetExpressCheckout
>   RETURNURL =
>   http://www.website.com/return.php
>   CANCELURL =
>   http://www.website.com/cancel.php
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE =
>   USD
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION = SALE
>   L_BILLINGTYPE0 =
>   RecurringPayments
>   L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0 = SameEveryTime
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT = 1.00
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT = 1.00
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC = Labs
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 = Lab 1
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0 = 10101
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0 = 1
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 = 1.00
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0 = Download

2) **Login into your PayPal account and click on “Accept and Continue”**

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-2EJ022116H3067544

Buyer logs into his PayPal account and click on the button “Agree and Continue”,
then he will be redirect to RETURNURL+ token+ PayerID:

http://www.website.com/return.php?token=EC-2EJ022116H3067544&PayerID=HHHAPCFUM9ULW

3) Then you can run CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile + token:

> PROFILEREFERENCE=RPInvoice123
>   PROFILESTARTDATE=2016-08-17T14:30:00Z
>   SUBSCRIBERNAME=Mr Sub Scriber
>   METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
>   TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
>   DESC=SameEveryTime
>   AMT = 1.00
>   BILLINGPERIOD=Day
>   BILLINGFREQUENCY=3
>   VERSION=86.0
>   MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=1
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=1.00
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Lab 1
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=10101
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
>   L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments
>   L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=SameEveryTime
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital

and this is the NVP Response:

> PROFILEID=**I-TOKEN123456**
>   PROFILESTATUS=ActiveProfile
>   TIMESTAMP=2013-11-22T04:06:50Z
>   CORRELATIONID=2b5be15a871ff
>   ACK=Success
>   VERSION=86.0
>   BUILD=5908853

**Documentation**:
[ECRecurringPayments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/)

API references (NVP)
[SetExpressCheckout API request](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
[CreateRecurringPayment API request](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)